# How to set fullscreen in Android R?

Tags: android, android-layout, fullscreen, android-5.0-lollipop, android-11

I need to put a screen in fullscreen in my app. For this I am using this code:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_photo)
```

However, the `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN` flag is deprecated.

My app supports Android Lollipop (API 21) to Android R (API 30).
What is the correct way to make a screen go fullscreen?

Answer (score 71):

**KOTLIN**

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_container)
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
    } else {
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
    }
}
```

if this doesn't help, try to remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the layout file

**JAVA**

```
class Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
@SuppressWarnings("DEPRECATION")
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.layout_container);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        final WindowInsetsController insetsController = getWindow().getInsetsController();
        if (insetsController != null) {
            insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
        }
    } else {
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: What is the type of **window** object here and how should it be initialized in **Java**? @Andriy D.

Comment: @andriy D. final WindowInsetsController insetsController = getWindow().getInsetsController();
this line is cause of javaNullPointerException. how to solve it?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.WindowInsetsController com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.getWindowInsetsController()' on a null object reference`

Comment: @user924 could you provide your activity/fragment, please?

Comment: Have error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.WindowInsetsController com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.getWindowInsetsController()' on a null object reference.In oder words getWindow() retun null.How to solve it?

Comment: @SaeidZ could you provide your activity/fragment, please?

Comment: @AndriyD. My activity is like as you write on your answer. I added getWindow().getInsetsController(); before the setContentView(R.layout.main_layout); But when i call getWindow() after setContentView  work fine and don't return null. I guess we have to call getWindow().getInsetsController(); afetr setContentView().

Comment: @SaeidZ yes, exactly. I've updated the answer, thanks for the comment.

Comment: you can't use it in `onCreate` t it should be in `onAttachedToWindow`. Check `public @Nullable WindowInsetsController getWindowInsetsController() {
        if (mAttachInfo != null) {
            return mAttachInfo.mViewRootImpl.getInsetsController();
        }`

Comment: and it's wrong that after `DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_layout)` it won't be `null`!

Comment: @SaeidZ no, you aren't right. `getWindow().getInsetsController()` won't work after `setContentView` in `onCreate`, only in `onAttachedToWindow`

Comment: @user924 Thanks. I don't know it work or no, but when use it before setContentView(), that return null. I think in newer androids (api 30) insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars()); method is ineffective and only set full screen style for activity is enough to make that full screen.

Comment: Incorrect, this is just a equivalent of `getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)` not `getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)` they behave different as when you swipe down to screen the status bar will remain unlike `WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN` where it goes back hidden

Comment: Use the compat version of WindowInsets.Type to get rid of the api check

Answer (score 16):

I had problem like user924

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.WindowInsetsController com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.getWindowInsetsController()' on a null object reference`

I could fix this problem by adding full screen setting code **after** `setContentView`. Also, usually, full screen will be screen without not only status bar, but also navigation bar too. Furthermore, just `hide()` method isn't enough. If we put only this line, when we swipe down screen to see status bar, it comes down, but never goes up again. By setting `systemBarBehavior`, we can make status bar and navigation bar appear temporarily only when we swipe just like full screen what we know.

```
setContentView(R.layout.YOUR_LAYOUT)

//Set full screen after setting layout content
@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
    val controller = window.insetsController

    if(controller != null) {
        controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
        controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
    }
} else {
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
}
```

Answer (score 11):

For API >= 30, use [`WindowInsetsController.hide()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowInsetsController#hide(int)):

```
window.insetsController.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
```

Comment: this solution will need a condition on version sdk

Comment: What is the type of **window** object here and how should it be initialized in **Java**?@Mimouni @Saurabh Thorat

Comment: @RAWNAKYAZDANI For Java, use `getWindow()` in your activity

Comment: @SaurabhThorat hide() is non static method and i can not use it static onCreate method. how to solve it?

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.WindowInsetsController com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.getWindowInsetsController()' on a null object reference`

Comment: remember you can't use it in `onCreate` t it should be in `onAttachedToWindow`. Check `public @Nullable WindowInsetsController getWindowInsetsController() {
        if (mAttachInfo != null) {
            return mAttachInfo.mViewRootImpl.getInsetsController();
        }`

Comment: window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
[For Kotlin, works]

Answer (score 4):

The code runs on real phones with Android 4.0 (API 14) to 10 (API 29) and on SDK phone emulator with Android R (API 30).

Write the theme for splash activity in style resources.

```
 <!--Splash screen theme-->
  <style name="SplashTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
  <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/colorSplashBackground</item>
  </style>
```

It's enough. No code is need to hide bar for splash activity.

Main activity.

Use the theme.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="myAppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

Write code in MainActivity class.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
    // Hide bar when you want. For example hide bar in landscape only
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        hideStatusBar_AllVersions();
    }
    setContentView( R.layout.activity_main );
    // Add your code
    }
```

Implement methods.

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
void hideStatusBar_Deprecated() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {  // < 16
        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    } else {  // 16...29
        View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
        if (ab != null) { ab.hide(); }

        getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    }
}

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.R) // >= 30
void hideStatusBar_Actual() {
    View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
    decorView.getWindowInsetsController().hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars());
}

void hideStatusBar_AllVersions(){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        hideStatusBar_Deprecated();
    } else {
        hideStatusBar_Actual();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not working for Android 30 emulator

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {     
 window.insetsController!!.hide(android.R.style.Theme_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen)
}
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

```
fullScreenButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

                    WindowInsetsController controller = getWindow().getInsetsController();
                    //BEFORE TOGGLE
//                    System.out.println(controller.getSystemBarsAppearance());
//                    System.out.println(controller.getSystemBarsBehavior());
                    if(controller != null) {
                        if (controller.getSystemBarsBehavior() == 0) {
                            controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
                            controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE);
                        } else {
                            controller.show(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() | WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars());
                            controller.setSystemBarsBehavior(WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_BARS_BY_TOUCH);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams attrs = getWindow().getAttributes();
                    attrs.flags ^= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
                    getWindow().setAttributes(attrs);
                }
                //AFTER TOGGLE
                //                    System.out.println(controller.getSystemBarsAppearance());
//                    System.out.println(controller.getSystemBarsBehavior());
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   override fun onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow()
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        val controller = window.insetsController
        if (controller != null) {
            controller.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars() or WindowInsets.Type.navigationBars())
            controller.systemBarsBehavior =
                WindowInsetsController.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }
    }
}

@Suppress("DEPRECATION")
private fun makeFullScreen() {
    // Remove Title
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
        window.setFlags(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
        )
    }
    // Hide the toolbar
    supportActionBar?.hide()
}
```