# What are the replacement of these function and threads in java?

Tags: java, android, android-fullscreen

Using: targetSdkVersion (API Level) 30.

It's showing 'Handler()' is deprecated.

```
private void initDelay() {
        new Handler().postDelayed(() -> LaunchNextActivity(), SPLASH_DELAY_IN_MILLIS);
    }
```

Trying to remove bottom navigation soft keys in android for that using:

```
public void FullScreen() {
            View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
            decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
        }
```

Here also showing: 'SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION' is deprecated, 'SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY' is deprecated, 'setSystemUiVisibility(int)' is deprecated. What are the replacements of all these.

Below are attached images for better understanding.

[image]

[image]

Comment: When something gets deprecated, then the documentation usually tells you what to use instead. Check [`SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION) for example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Enable Fullscreen

you can use:   ***window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())***

```kotlin
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private fun enableFullScreenMode() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.insetsController?.hide(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
        } else {
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
            )
        }
    }

   // Bonus: Disable Full Screen Mode
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    private fun disableFullScreenMode() {
        // Note you need to check version via Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R
        // to avoid future errors
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            window.insetsController?.show(WindowInsets.Type.statusBars())
        } else {

            window?.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        }
    }
```

[More info here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835053/how-to-set-fullscreen-in-android-r)

2. Handler() is now deprecated you can use: ***Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())***

```
val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())
handler.postDelayed( ... )
```